# How to send ParseObject to cloud function correctly?

Tags: android, parse-platform

When I try to send a ParseObject to cloud function

```
params.put("obj", myParseObject);
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground(functionName, params,...
```

I get an error `IllegalArgumentException("ParseObjects not allowed here"`)

What is the correct way to send ParseObject to clould funciton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send ParseObjects to cloud code. You should instead send the object Id string and then fetch the object on cloud code.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions expect params as JSON objects, just as in a normal JS backend.

```
In an App as in flutter I do Map<String, dynamic> and it automatically converts through the library to a JSON object.

I also have to convert the parseObject on my store into a JSON object to generate a map ( this is just necessary in flutter )

final parseObjectMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(boardObject.toJson());
      saveWetSuitFunction
          .execute(parameters: myMap)
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry that this is a bit late, but you can try `obj.saveInBackground()`

This saves this object to the server in a background thread. This is preferable to using `ParseObject.save()`, unless your code is already running from a background thread.

You can find a reference here:
http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveInBackground%28%29